# Getting sum of values from object in array using jq

Tags: json, count, jq

I'm trying to get the total amount for a specific value in a array.
The input would be something like

```
[{
    "name": "mars",
    "runner":  [
        {
        "foo": null,
        "idle": true
        },
        {
        "foo": null,
        "idle": true
        },
        {
        "foo": null,
        "idle": false
        }

    ],
        "name": "june",
        "runner": [
        {
        "foo": null,
        "idle": true
        },
        {
        "foo": null,
        "idle": true
        },
        {
        "foo": null,
        "idle": true
        }
    ]
}]
```

The desired output

> [ {"name" : "mars", "idle" : 2"},{"name" : "june", "idle" : 1"} ]

I tried using select and map, but I'm not understanding exactly how jq is working, for instance, I tried the following query

```
jq  ' .[] | select(.runner[].idle == true) | {name: .name}'
```

The result was

> {   "nome": "mars" } {   "nome": "mars" } {   "nome": "june" } {
>   "nome": "june" } {   "nome": "june" }

(3x true in june and 2x in mars) I can keep parsing the json and get to the result I want, but it doesn't seems right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input data doesn't seem to correspond exactly with your posting. I'll assume you meant:

```
[{"name":"mars",
  "runner":[{"foo":null,"idle":true},{"foo":null,"idle":true},{"foo":null,"idle":false}]},
 {"name":"june",
  "runner":[{"foo":null,"idle":true},{"foo":null,"idle":true},{"foo":null,"idle":true}]}]
```

#### length

A reasonable approach would be to rely on the builtin `length` function:

```
map( { name, idle: (.runner | map(select(.idle)) | length)} )
```

#### count

A better (e.g. more efficient) solution would be to define a function that can count:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $i (0; .+1);
```

Here `s` is any filter that produces a stream of values.  A solution to the problem at hand could then be written as follows:

```
map( {name, idle: count(.runner[] | select(.idle))} )
```

#### Output

The output in both cases:

```
[
  {
    "name": "mars",
    "idle": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "june",
    "idle": 3
  }
]
```